# Simplesamlphp_auth module in Drupal 8 + Simplesaml library

Tags: drupal-8, simplesamlphp

I have successfully installed simplesamlphp and configured my system as SP. And also able to login to IDP. Now I want to integrate it in my drupal8 project.
So as per the installation instructions, I downloaded simplesamlphp_auth module in my drupal project module folder and refreshed admin panel to install it, throws an error like this-

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.</br></br><em class="placeholder">SimpleSAML\Error\CriticalConfigurationError</em>: The configuration (config/config.php) is invalid: Missing configuration file in <em class="placeholder">SimpleSAML\Error\CriticalConfigurationError::fromException()</em> (line <em class="placeholder">78</em> of <em class="placeholder">vendor/simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp/lib/SimpleSAML/Error/CriticalConfigurationError.php</em>). <pre class="backtrace">SimpleSAML_Configuration::getInstance() (Line: 43)
```

SimpleSAML\Auth\Simple->__construct('default-sp') (Line: 59)
Drupal\simplesamlphp_auth\Service\SimplesamlphpAuthManager->__construct(Object) (Line: 262)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->createService(Array, 'simplesamlphp_auth.manager') (Line: 171)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('simplesamlphp_auth.manager', 1) (Line: 480)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->resolveServicesAndParameters(Array) (Line: 230)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->createService(Array, 'simplesamlphp_auth_event_subscriber') (Line: 171)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('simplesamlphp_auth_event_subscriber') (Line: 105)
Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.request', Object) (Line: 127)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 68)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 57)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 99)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 78)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 50)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 664)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)

Please help me with this issue.

Comment: in directory vendor/simplesaml/simplesaml/ there will be a directory called config make sure if config.php file is present there or not !

Comment: Thanks @vishwa. Yes this error was because config and metadata folders were empty. Resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After spending whole day on this issue, I finally resolved this error by copying docroot/simplesamlphp/config and metadata folder in vendor/simplesamlphp/config and metadata.

Thanks.